# How to find duplicate values from a new array in Python?

Tags: python

I'm still extremely new to python, and currently stuck on this problem. Basically, I take a list of numbers and add them to each other, starting at zero. The code writes out each line into a new array. If in this new array I find two of the same numbers, it stops and returns that number. The original list of values repeats itself if no duplicate is found.

Here's what I have so far:

```
file = open("list.txt", "r")

array1 = file.readlines()

total = 0
finalValue = 0

for i in range(0,len(array1)):
    array1[i] = int(array1[i])

array2 = []
i = 0
counter = 0

while finalValue == 0:

    total += array1[i]
    array2.append(total)
    print(array2)

    for c in range(0,len(array2)):
        if (total == array2[c]): 
            counter += 1

        if counter == 2:
            finalValue = total

            break

    if (i == len(array1)-1):
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1
    counter = 0
print(finalValue)
```

I think the counter is working, but it never finds a duplicate, i.e. it never hits the second counter.

Comment: please provide input and desired output; i.e. a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Link to [list](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Whjpr3jxR9bqBEhU8t-Hdiy12EHNzHQQ) @hiroprotagonist

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to make your code simpler in Python, but first of all, your problem is that the condition `total == array2[c]` compares elements of the array with your `total`, not with each other. 
For example, if your array is `[1,3,3]`, the second `3` would be compared to `4`, not to `3`.

If I understand your code, I think you want to change `total == array2[c]` to `array1[i] == array2[c]` - but that's just an immediate fix, you can use python's list techniques to make this code much simpler.

Comment: How do you mean compared to 4? So you're saying I should make a new variable?

Comment: If you think the beginning of the code clarifies your question, edit it into the question.

Comment: Though if I understand your code, I think you want to change `total == array2[c]` to `array1[i] == array2[c]`